# How do I get my data in my heatmap?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, matplotlib

I've programmed Conways Game of Life in Python and now I'm trying to display the simple data that it gives me as an output in a heat map.
This is my current code:

```
from Tkinter import *

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import time
import numpy as np
import random

size_x = 100
size_y = 10

# create the matrices
cell = [[0 for row in range(0, size_y)] for col in range(0, size_x)]
live = [[0 for row in range(0, size_y)] for col in range(0, size_x)]
temp = [[0 for row in range(0, size_y)] for col in range(0, size_x)]

# process and draw the next frame
def frame():
    process()
    draw()
    root.after(100, frame)

# load the initial data
def load(initial=0.5):
    for y in range(0, size_y):
        for x in range(0, size_x):
            if random.random()<initial: live[x][y] = 1
            temp[x][y] = 0


# Applying rules
def process():
    for y in range(0, size_y):
        for x in range(0, size_x):
            lives = live_neighbors(x,y)
            if live[x][y] == 1:
                if lives < 2 or lives > 3:
                    temp[x][y] = 0
                else:
                    temp[x][y] = 1
            if live[x][y] == 0:
                if lives == 3:
                    temp[x][y] = 1
                else:
                    temp[x][y] = 0

    for y in range(0, size_y):
        for x in range(0, size_x):
            live[x][y] = temp[x][y]
#   live = temp

# Count live neighbors
def live_neighbors(a,b):
    lives = 0 
    if live[a][(b+1)%size_y] == 1: lives += 1
    if live[a][(b-1)%size_y] == 1: lives += 1   
    if live[(a+1)%size_x][b] == 1: lives += 1
    if live[(a+1)%size_x][(b+1)%size_y] == 1: lives += 1
    if live[(a+1)%size_x][(b-1)%size_y] == 1: lives += 1
    if live[(a-1)%size_x][b] == 1: lives += 1
    if live[(a-1)%size_x][(b+1)%size_y] == 1: lives += 1
    if live[(a-1)%size_x][(b-1)%size_y] == 1: lives += 1
    return lives

# Draw all cells
def draw():
    nLiving = 0
    nDead = 0
    for y in range(size_y):
        for x in range(size_x):
            if live[x][y]==0:
                canvas.itemconfig(cell[x][y], fill="black")
                nDead+=1
            if live[x][y]==1:
                canvas.itemconfig(cell[x][y], fill="white")
                nLiving+=1
    print nLiving,nDead


# count cells
def count():
    nLiving = 0
    nDead = 0
    for y in range(size_y):
        for x in range(size_x):
            if live[x][y]==0:
                nDead+=1
            if live[x][y]==1:
                nLiving+=1
    z = nLiving / 10.0
    print z,
    print "%"


def one_game(initial):
    load(initial)
    for gen in range(1, 101):
        print str(gen) + ":",
        count()
        process()

def many_games():
    numbers = range(1,51)
    for initial in numbers:
        print initial/100.0
        one_game(initial/100.0)


many_games()
#one_game(0.5)
```

The code for making a normal heat map with given input would be:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

x = np.array( [[11,12,13], [21,22,23], [31,32,33]] )

p = ax.pcolormesh(x)
fig.colorbar(p)
plt.show()
```

How do I get my data (which in this case would be, the generations, the value which *initializes* the one_game() function, and *nLiving*) into an array?

Comment: If you're going to post code (which is good), you should try to make it working code. There are a bunch of indentation errors in the code above, like lines 27, 36, 47, 81, and others where you just have some random extra (or missing) spaces. Also, it's not entirely clear to me what you're trying to get into an array, but it looks like you just need to add some return values to your count() and one_game() and many_games() functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure this is what you're intending, but it produced a pretty output heat map :)

```
def count():
    nLiving = 0
    nDead = 0
    for y in range(size_y):
        for x in range(size_x):
            if live[x][y]==0:
                nDead+=1
            if live[x][y]==1:
                nLiving+=1
    z = nLiving / 10.0
    print("nLiving over ten is: ", z,)
    print("%")
    return nLiving


def one_game(initial):
    load(initial)
    gen_array = []
    for gen in range(1, 101):
        print("Gen: ", str(gen) + ":",)
        nLiving = count()
        process()
        gen_array.append(nLiving)
    return gen_array

def many_games():
    gen_output = []
    numbers = range(1,51)
    for initial in numbers:
        print(initial/100.0)
        gen_array = one_game(initial/100.0)
        gen_output.append(gen_array)
    return gen_output

gen_output = many_games()
#one_game(0.5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)

x = np.array( gen_output )

p = ax.pcolormesh(x)
fig.colorbar(p)
plt.show()
```

That is just code modified from your count function to the end of the file. Basically you just need to return the output from the functions that you're calling into the right kind of data structures, I think...

Comment: I don't really understand why you put the the text from the print command in the count function into brackets, but thank you, I wouldn't have been able to figure this out on my own (I'm new to python & programming in general).

Comment: @air See the note on Python 3 "Print Is A Function" https://docs.python.org/3.0/whatsnew/3.0.html

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm not familiar with python 3

Comment: Yea, I just only have Python3 on this computer, so I had to modify print statements, but I think they should still work on Python2 as well. Glad that got it working for you :)